# Select three highest values by comparing different columns in a row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which returns a row based on student_id, and it contains marks of six quizzes,  with column names like Quiz1,   Quiz2,   Quiz3,   Quiz4 ,  Quiz5 &   Quiz6.

I want to select only the top 3 highest marks secure by the student and then take its average and then compare that value of average with another column "Pass_Avg".

If the value of top 3 quiz mark average is greater than equal to the value of "Pass_Avg" then just simply change the value of result column with 'P' else 'F'.

So I was trying to get the highest value by doing something like this

```
SELECT
CASE

     WHEN Quiz1 >= Quiz2 AND Quiz1 >= Quiz3 and Quiz1 >= Quiz4 and Quiz1 >= Quiz5 and Quiz1 >= Quiz6 THEN Quiz1
     WHEN Quiz2 >= Quiz1 AND Quiz2 >= Quiz3 and Quiz2 >= Quiz4 and Quiz2 >= Quiz5 and Quiz2 >= Quiz6 THEN  Quiz2
     WHEN Quiz3 >= Quiz1 AND Quiz3 >= Quiz2 and Quiz3 >= Quiz4 and Quiz3 >= Quiz5 and Quiz3 >= Quiz6 THEN  Quiz3
     WHEN Quiz4 >= Quiz1 AND Quiz4 >= Quiz2 and Quiz4 >= Quiz3 and Quiz4 >= Quiz5 and Quiz4 >= Quiz6 THEN  Quiz4
     WHEN Quiz5 >= Quiz1 AND Quiz5 >= Quiz2 and Quiz5 >= Quiz3 and Quiz5 >= Quiz4 and Quiz5 >= Quiz6 THEN  Quiz5
     WHEN Quiz6 >= Quiz1 AND Quiz6 >= Quiz2 and Quiz6 >= Quiz3 and Quiz6 >= Quiz4 and Quiz6 >= Quiz5 THEN  Quiz6
     ELSE Quiz1
    END AS Highest from dbo.Student where student_id= '01'
```

Can anyone please suggest that how should I try to do this since I am having difficulty in getting the second and third highest value.

Comment: So every student has a different Pass_Avg? And you take a student's three highest quiz results, add them up, divide the sum by three and compare the result with Pass_Avg? Can there be NULLs? If so, would you divide by two if there were only two quiz results for a student?

Comment: Why don't you make a different table with quiz results? Storing row values (which is what quiz results should be) in columns is a horrible database design. What if there's a new quiz next year?

Comment: The scenario is different actually i only change it for simplicity and to answer your queries: 

So every student has a different Pass_Avg? 
YES

And you take a student's three highest quiz results, add them up, divide the sum by three and compare the result with Pass_Avg?
YES

Can there be NULLs?
NO


and if i could change the db design i definitely would but i just cant hope you understand :)

Comment: I don't really have time right now to make a good example, but you should look into t-sql's `PIVOT` to convert your column values to row values. It's not easy if you have never used it, but once your quiz results are *rows* (with `PIVOT`) instead of *columns*, the query is trivial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your database design. You should have a table student_quiz with a student_id and quiz_id. Instead you have the quizzes in columns which makes their access more complicated. Use UNION ALL to mimic the better database design. (We'll select pass_avg along with it to use it later). Then give the records row numbers per student, with 1 being the highest quiz result, 2 the second and so on. Then pick the best three and do your aggregations.

```
select
  student_id, 
  sum(quiz),
  min(pass_avg),
  case when sum(quiz) / 3 >= min(pass_avg) then 'yes' else 'no' end as passed
from
(
  select 
    student_id, 
    quiz,
    pass_avg,
    row_number() over (partition by student_id order by quiz desc) as rn
  from
  (
    select student_id, quiz1 as quiz, pass_avg from student 
    union all
    select student_id, quiz2 as quiz, pass_avg from student 
    union all
    select student_id, quiz3 as quiz, pass_avg from student 
    union all
    select student_id, quiz4 as quiz, pass_avg from student 
    union all
    select student_id, quiz5 as quiz, pass_avg from student 
    union all
    select student_id, quiz6 as quiz, pass_avg from student 
  )
where rn in (1,2,3)
group by student_id
order by student_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
select Quiz1,'Quiz1' from dbo.Student where student_id= '01'
UNION ALL
select Quiz2,'Quiz2' from dbo.Student where student_id= '01'
UNIONA ALL
...
order by 1 desc
```

To get top 3? Does SQL Server support LIMIT? Or was it TOP only?

Attempt using TOP:

```
select top 3 * from
(
    select Quiz1,'Quiz1' from dbo.Student where student_id= '01'
    UNION ALL
    select Quiz2,'Quiz2' from dbo.Student where student_id= '01'
    UNION ALL
    ...
    order by 1 desc
)
```

May work...